# API Facebook - Secure Canvas URL

Tags: api

Estou tentando fazer com que um aplicativo funcione no Facebook e tenha interação com o site que estou desenvolvendo. O objetivo é que o usuário faça login pelo Facebook no site.

Acontece que toda vez que tento adicionar o site nas configurações de API do Facebook, acusa esse erro:

`This must be derived from Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL ou Secure Page Tab URL.`

[image: Imagem ilustrativa do problema]

Vejam que na imagem tem o campo **App Domains**. É esse campo que não entra de jeito nenhum. É obrigatório ser HTTPS ? Não entendo.

Se sim, como faço para configurar isso no servidor ?

E no campo **Secure Page Tab URL** tem que por esse **websiteseguro.com** para funcionar. A questão é dá para enganar o Facebook e deixar assim. Mas estar assim o aplicativo não funciona no Facebook, mas funciona no site.

Enfim, Facebook até pra isso está muito chato de usar.

Sé Loco Cachorrera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver essa questão.

O Facebook nesse campo aceita apenas o protocolo **HTTPS**.

Ou seja, se quisermos colocar alguma página do site em uma TAB (Aba) no Facebook precisamos contratar o serviço SSL da hospedagem, que faz com que o domínio também seja acessado pelo protocolo **HTTPS**.